# Vim SCP parameter with private public key pair

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, scp, vim, private-key

Currently, I am trying to edit a file on a remote server using Vim's built-in netrw plugin. I can SSH fine into my Amazon EC2 server using a command like this:

```
ssh -i <keyfile> bitname@<ec2-address>
```

However, I'd like to be able to use my own Vim configurations and have been trying to use scp like this:

```
:e scp://user@<ec2-address>//
```

But without a parameter to enter my keyfile, I get a permission denied (publickey) error.

Is there a parameter that I can use to enter my keyfile or another solution I am overlooking?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I haven't got Vim's `netrw` plugin, but try the following.

Create an ssh client config file for your host. Put the following in `$HOME/.ssh/config`:

```
Host myserveralias
Hostname ec-address
User user
IdentityFile /path/to/keyfile
PasswordAuthentication no
```

Replace the values according to your host of course. Then login using an scp URL like this:

```
:e scp://myserveralias//
```

Most ssh cliets on Linux honour the client configuration file (also a sytem-wide one in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` (not to be confused with `sshd_config`). I hope your plugin will do so too. For more configuration options see `man ssh_config`. Debugging using `ssh -vvv` usually helps you out.

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly. Another alternative solution I found was to use Transmit to mount as a drive. Then using Terminal, I could open up the files in Vim.